# Cloudera Search Map Widget with iso alpha-2 country codes

Tags: search, solr, schema, bigdata, cloudera

I discovered the amazing widget from Cloudera Search called Map. I would like to use it to display the count of records by country but it only works with iso alpha-3 country-codes. I only have iso alpha-2 country codes values in my records (see the difference here http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm).

I would like to know how could I obtain an iso alpha-3 country code? I would like to mention that my raw data is in csv format and I have a field called Country that contains the full country name and another one called Country_Code that stores iso apha-2 country codes.

I tried to modify both the SOLR schema.xml and the Morphlines file but with no positive results. Any idea is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem actually. I managed to solve it by creating a custom Morphlines command, as outlined below.

**Build a custom Morphlines command.**
In Morphlines, you can build your own command rather easily. (See [Implementing your own Custom Command](http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/kite-morphlines/morphlinesReferenceGuide.html)). Here is a sample of the code you could use in your command builder:

```java
// Nested class:

private static final class ConvertCountryCode extends AbstractCommand {
    private final String fieldName;

    public ConvertCountryCode(Command Builder builder, Config config, Command parent, Command child, MorphlineContext context) {
        super(builder, config, parent, child, context);
        this.fileName = getConfigs().getString(config, "field");
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarning("unchecked")
    protected boolean doProcess(Record record) {
        ListIterator iter = record.get(fieldName).listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Locale locale = new Locale ("", iter.next().toString());
            String result = locale.getISO3Country();
            iter.set(result);
        }
        return super.doProcess(record);
    }
}
```

Once you have your command builder, you can edit your Morphlines conf file to add the command, like this:

```
commands: [{
    convertCountryCode {
        field: Country_Code
    }
}
```

When used, this command would replace all your ISO Alpha-2 codes with ISO Alpha-3 as you add them to your index. I've tested this solution, and it works! Make sure to add your package to the list of command imports for your Morphline.

**Use Java command**
Alternatively, if you don't want to build a custom command, you can use the [Java command](http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/kite-morphlines/morphlinesReferenceGuide.html#/java).